# Symfony2 valid constraint on form element does not show custom error message

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am constructing a form for users to submit a DMCA complaint, and one of the design requirements is to allow them to enter one or more URLs. To that end, I've created an entity (DMCAComplaint), and a child entity (DMCAComplaintURL) which is joined to DMCAComplaint in a Doctrine OneToMany relationship.

In order to validate the URL entries via regex, I have the following assertion set up:

```
// src: Bundle/Event/DMCAComplaintURL.php

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/(https?:\/\/)?([\w].)*example.com(\/.*)?/"),
 *     message="Please enter a URL within our site"
 * )
 */
protected $url;
```

And in the complaint:

```
// src: Bundle/Entity/DMCAComplaint.php

/**
 * @var \DMCAComplaintURL
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DMCAComplaintURL", mappedBy="dmcaComplaint", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="dmca_complaint_id")
 * })
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
protected $urls;
```

While the assertion works, it only gives the following error: `This value is not valid.` I would like it to have a custom message, as outlined in the `DMCAComplaintUrl $url` property. Is there a way to make this bubble up to the `Valid` assertion? or can I use something else to get what I need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set error_bubbling to true on your form field:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling